# Lectura de valores escritos en tarjeta sin contacto en Python

Tags: python

He utilizado el siguiente código para obtener el UID de una tarjeta sin contacto pero no consigo leer los valores que tiene grabados en su interior.

Me gustaría leer todos los valores que tiene escritos en sus registros.

```
from smartcard.scard import *

hresult, hcontext = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER)

assert hresult==SCARD_S_SUCCESS

hresult, readers = SCardListReaders(hcontext, [])

assert len(readers)>0

reader = readers[0]

hresult, hcard, dwActiveProtocol = SCardConnect(
    hcontext,
    reader,
    SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
    SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1)

#Comando que tenemos que enviar para conseguir el UID
hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard,dwActiveProtocol,[0xFF,0xCA,0x00,0x00,0x00])

print ("Modelo de Lector de Tarjeta:", reader)

print ("El UID de la tarjeta en lector es: ", response)
```

Comment: indica por favor qué tipo de errores te surgieron, así como un [mcve].

Comment: No son errores, el problema es que [0xFF,0xCA,0x00,0x00,0x00] encuentro el UID de la tarjeta pero no se donde ni como buscar los datos que contiene @fedorqui